# Incorrect Document Storage Displayed in MacBook Air Running on macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, big-sur, storage, disk-volume, document-management

I am using MacBook Air 2017 with macOS Big Sur. When I check my storage in About this Mac → Storage → Manage it shows Documents taking Zero KB but actually it contains files worth **4.64 GB**. I have tried rebooting several times but it didn't work for me.

[image: Documents Zero KB, File Browser showing entries of MBs]

[image: QuickLook on folder called Documents showing 4.64 GB]

Comment: The Storage indicator uses the Spotlight database, so you could try rebuilding the Spotlight index. However, the Storage manager is a pretty unreliable 'broad strokes' tool.

Comment: Can you add more detail and an solution for this!!
his!!

Comment: Either use the Terminal command `sudo mdutil -E /` or follow Apple's advice here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201716.

Comment: @benwiggy is it safe to do because I don't know what will be the outcome and I don't wanna hamper my system to...

Comment: Why would I suggest something that wasn't 'safe'? Other people would comment if I asked you to do something destructive. You can always use Apple's method in the link I gave, if you prefer. But a quick google of "mac rebuild spotlight index" will supply several pages listing this command. In any case: you have a backup, don't you?